# File Synchronization by Sync Framework work on runtime

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm working on File Synchronization by Sync Framework. I followed File Synchronization Provider Sample but my scenario is DetectChangesOnFileSystemReplica will work on runtime instead of checking Sync Now everytime.

I knew that we can do this by using Threading and Do-While to detect changes on source folder every second but it is a bad idea, right?

Is there any way to check the changes of source folder (like as new file created, renamed, deleted) on runtime?

btw, i tried to use SyncToy but it's still use "Sync now" instead of Sync on runtime.

How did DropBox/SkyDrive do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create handlers for your file system events which would allow you to Detect Changes and run the Sync.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/1e6szwcw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sounds nice. I will try this.
Thanks :)

Comment: Did you get a chance to try this?  Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

you have to explicitly invoke the sync. it will not automatically fire based on some file event. as neverseenjack stated, you can listen for file events and run the sync. but even then, you still have to invoke the sync explicitly.